# Results of f_classif() not so intuitive in ANOVA model

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I am running `f_classif()` where my label has 3 classes which are (+1,0,-1) to predict the AT&T stock price in the next X bars. I am trying to select from gazillion features using `f_classif()` based on the score it assigns to each column. Some of the features are assigned a very high F-score, sometimes higher than 300 to my surprise. One of these columns is the MACD of PNC bank which sounds extremely unintuitive to me. How can there be a predictive relationship here?

Do you have any opinion? How should I plot the feature and the label so that I can see that there is predictive power here? Something is odd. [My label and feature here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S9Da.png)
[image]